# How to merge 2 rows into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The code I used was:

```
SELECT
    AccountFK,
    CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Telecoms' Then B.TermFeeMethod END AS TelecomsTermMethod,
    CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Broadband' Then B.TermFeeMethod END AS BroadbandTermMethod,
    CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Mobile' Then B.TermFeeMethod END AS MobileTermMethod,
    CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Water' Then B.TermFeeMethod END AS WaterTermMethod,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY B.AccountFK ,B.TermFeeMethod ORDER BY A.CreatedDate DESC) AS RowNo
FROM 
    CRM.Contract.TermFeeTransaction AS A
    INNER JOIN ContractSnapshot AS B ON A.ContractFK = B.ContractID
WHERE 
CAST(b.CreatedDate as date) between '20180101' and '20190812'
AND B.TermFeeMethod IS NOT NULL 
AND ContractType IN
('Telecoms',
 'Broadband',
 'Mobile',
 'Water')
 and AccountFK = '12345'
```

The output I'm looking for would be only one row, however, I'm getting two rows instead. Does anybody know how to merge them into one?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT AccountFK,
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Telecoms' Then B.TermFeeMethod END) AS TelecomsTermMethod,
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Broadband' Then B.TermFeeMethod END) AS BroadbandTermMethod,
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Mobile' Then B.TermFeeMethod END) AS MobileTermMethod,
       MAX(CASE WHEN B.ContractType = 'Water' Then B.TermFeeMethod END) AS WaterTermMethod,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY B.AccountFK ,B.TermFeeMethod ORDER BY A.CreatedDate DESC) AS RowNo
FROM CRM.Contract.TermFeeTransaction A JOIN
     ContractSnapshot B
     ON A.ContractFK = B.ContractID
WHERE CAST(b.CreatedDate as date) between '20180101' and '20190812' AND
      B.TermFeeMethod IS NOT NULL AND
      ContractType IN ('Telecoms', 'Broadband', 'Mobile', 'Water') AND
      AccountFK = '12345'
GROUP BY AccountFK;
```

Note:  `A` and `B` are really bad choices for table aliases.  They are just arbitrary letters.  You should use `tft` and `cs` instead -- these are abbreviations for the table names.